# Cargar Play List de youtube en un sitio web

Tags: html, jquery, api, youtube-api

Hola lo que yo quiero es cargar una lista de reproducción en mi sitio web, que he hecho hasta ahora? :

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <!-- 1. The <iframe> (and video player) will replace this <div> tag. -->
    <div id="player"></div>

    <script>
  // 2. This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
  var tag = document.createElement('script');

  tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
  var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

  // 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
  //    after the API code downloads.
  var player;
  function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
      height: '360',
      width: '640',
      videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE',
      host: 'https://www.youtube.com',
      events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady,
        'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
      }
    });

  }

  // 4. The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
  function onPlayerReady(event) {
    event.target.playVideo();
  }

  // 5. The API calls this function when the player's state changes.
  //    The function indicates that when playing a video (state=1),
  //    the player should play for six seconds and then stop.
  var done = false;
  function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done) {
      setTimeout(stopVideo, 6000);
      done = true;
    }
  }
  function stopVideo() {
    player.loadPlaylist({
        playlist: 'PLn5lEmVWb0R8HHSUZ1v-qOVulU6UMl8_B',
        playerVars: { 'autoplay': 1, 'controls': 0,'autohide':1,'wmode':'opaque','origin':'http://localhost:8100' },
        host: 'https://www.youtube.com',
    });
  }
</script>
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

eso he hecho pero no funciona, carga el primer video bien pero al irse a cargar la playlist se daña, pues se queda cargando, incluso no necesito ese primer video que se reproduce, pero como no se llamar la play list desde el principio no tuve alternativa.

Aqui les agrego unas imagenes.

Asi se ve cuando carga el sitio 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Asi se ve cuando ya va a cargar la play list, ahi se ven los errores que saca y como carga, y de esa carga no pasa se queda asi. 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ERRORES

1.

```
www-widgetapi.js:100 Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided ('https://www.youtube.com') does not match the recipient window's origin ('http://seadoglabs.com').
h.B @ www-widgetapi.js:100
h.F @ www-widgetapi.js:97
setInterval (async)
Pa @ www-widgetapi.js:72
Za @ www-widgetapi.js:98
W @ www-widgetapi.js:81
Y @ www-widgetapi.js:102
onYouTubeIframeAPIReady @ home.html:19
(anonymous) @ www-widgetapi.js:124
(anonymous) @ www-widgetapi.js:124
```

2.

```
GET https://www.youtube.com/list_ajax?style=json&action_get_templist=1&video_ids=PLn5lEmVWb0R8HHSUZ1v-qOVulU6UMl8_B 400
iF @ base.js:2263
g.hF @ base.js:2247
VQ @ base.js:3158
g.WQ @ base.js:3150
o0 @ base.js:4524
E0 @ base.js:4540
g.h.iP @ base.js:6681
TP.a.K.(anonymous function) @ base.js:3035
g.h.eP @ base.js:6629
UP.a.C.(anonymous function) @ base.js:3039
(anonymous) @ www-embed-player.js:516
h.la @ www-embed-player.js:599
h.Ja @ www-embed-player.js:588
fi.A @ www-embed-player.js:584
```

3.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Ia' of null
    at b0.g.h.rx (base.js:7965)
g.h.rx @ base.js:7965
setTimeout (async)
g.wE @ base.js:2201
g.h.onReady @ base.js:6861
E0 @ base.js:4540
g.h.iP @ base.js:6681
TP.a.K.(anonymous function) @ base.js:3035
g.h.eP @ base.js:6629
UP.a.C.(anonymous function) @ base.js:3039
(anonymous) @ www-embed-player.js:516
h.la @ www-embed-player.js:599
h.Ja @ www-embed-player.js:588
fi.A @ www-embed-player.js:584
```

Si conocen alguna api o algo que me pueda llevar a la solucion del problema se los agradeceria.

Tambien al que se quiera comunicar por medio de slack aqui le dejo un link a un grupo de desarrollo 
`https://join.slack.com/t/sitim/shared_invite/enQtNTI1NTE4OTA0NjEwLTkyOWJhZTFhNTkxM2IyNGI1MDAwZDUzYWU2MGI2NWY4OGY2YWZkOTgyOGVjZTBlNjg0ODI3NTdlNTAyNDJkODQ`

Este es el sitio por si quieren ver o probar algo `http://seadoglabs.com/iq/pru/home.html`

Me base en esto: `https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference?hl=es#Playback_controls`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <!-- 1. The <iframe> (and video player) will replace this <div> tag. -->
    <div id="player"></div>

    <script>
  // 2. This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
  var tag = document.createElement('script');

  tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
  var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

  // 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
  //    after the API code downloads.
  var player;
  function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
      height: '360',
      width: '640',
      videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE',
      host: 'https://www.youtube.com',
      events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady,
        'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
      }
    });

  }

  // 4. The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
  function onPlayerReady(event) {
    event.target.playVideo();
  }

  // 5. The API calls this function when the player's state changes.
  //    The function indicates that when playing a video (state=1),
  //    the player should play for six seconds and then stop.
  var done = false;
  function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done) {
      setTimeout(stopVideo, 6000);
      done = true;
    }
  }
  function stopVideo() {
    player.loadPlaylist({
     playlist: 'PLn5lEmVWb0R8HHSUZ1v-qOVulU6UMl8_B',
     playerVars: { 'autoplay': 1, 'controls': 0,'autohide':1,'wmode':'opaque','origin':'http://localhost:8100' },
     host: 'https://www.youtube.com',
    });
  }
</script>
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```